# Android - Make Sure ImageView Stays on Screen

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a Android project where I have an `ImageView` that moves to the left every time a button is pressed using

```
tButton.setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(10, 10, new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {                    
             player1.setX(player1.getX() - 1);
        }
}));
```

I don't want this `ImageView` to leave the screen, and so I've tried adding another `ImageView` to the edge, and tried using

```
tButton.setOnTouchListener(new RepeatListener(10, 10, new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Rect p1 = new Rect();
            player1.getHitRect(p1);

            Rect sL = new Rect();
            lSide.getHitRect(sL);

          if(Rect.intersects(p1, sL))
            {
                player1.setX(player1.getX() + 100);
            }
            else
            {
                player1.setX(player1.getX() - 1);
            }
        }
}));
```

The problem is that after the two objects interest, the `onClick` method never seemed to get called again. Is there something that I'm forgetting to do, or is there an easier way to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way to solve the problem.  Use `imageView.getLocationOnScreen()` to get the x and y position of the view on screen.  Then you can check and see if moving it again would cause you to have a negative X (move off the screen to the left) or if X+imageView.getWidth()>screen_width (move off to the right).